# How to save array in django caches?

Tags: arrays, django, caching

I am facing issues with saving arrays in django cache. When I retrieve the array [['hello',1],[2,3]] from django cache, it gets converted to `[[&#39;hello&#39;, 1]`, [2, 3]]. Essentially, the single quotes get changed to ascii character code. This issue doesn't happen with simple strings. How can I avoid this issue?

```
s = [['hello',1],[2,3]]
    s1 = json.dumps(s)
    cache.set('testv',s1)
    a = json.loads(cache.get('testv'))
    return render(request,'sm/technical_tt.html',{'start':a})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That can only same simple `string` not `object` so you need to `dump array` into `string` for save and for access just `load string` into `array` Ex:**

```
import json
arr = [['hello',1],[2,3]]
arr = json.dumps(arr)
# Here you can save 'arr' var in cache and it'll save as
# Output => arr = '[["hello", 1], [2, 3]]'

arr = '[["hello", 1], [2, 3]]'
arr = json.loads(arr)

# Output => arr = [["hello", 1], [2, 3]]
```